# How can I edit the boot configuration data (BCD) store of another disk?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, bcdedit

[BCDEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(WS.10).aspx) allows for editing the bcd store of the current system drive (C: drive). Is there also a way to create and edit the bcd store of a secondary drive, so the system can boot from it later on? (For instance, by physically moving the drive to another machine as the primary disk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run your `BCDEDIT` commands using the `/store` parameter:

```
bcdedit /store E:\boot\BCD /enum
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit a non-system BCD by simply dropping it on [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) icon.

The system BCD is opened on start of program by default.

The concept of Visual BCD Editor is to avoid typing and execute all commands through visual selection in a graphical environment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find this thread sooner ;)

Comment: @Max - Same here, just saw this question/ thread. :) Enjoy

Comment: Note that Visual BCD Editor is only free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) has been around for long as well. Is a very popular one in addition to Visual BCD. This tool is free for non-commercial use.

There are a few more niche apps in similar space as well.

I prefer EasyBCD for simple operations as its easier & cleaner (safer to use in case you're not sure what you're doing), but I'd think that Visual BCD has deeper parameter change-ability.

PS: There are some issues with UEFI/ Windows that EasyBCD says it cannot handle.